# Some quotient of $[0,1]$ is homeomorphic to $[0,1] \times [0,1]$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I have been unable to solve this problem.  I imagine you would start with some bijection $$f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1] \times [0,1]$$ But I don't get how any topological argument could be made here with an arbitrary bijection.

Comment: There is no continuous bijection. What you want to start with is a continuous *sur*jection. Look up space-filling curves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is pretty easy using Mike Miller's hint.  Let $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1] \times [0,1]$ be a continuous surjection, and set $x \sim y$ if and only if $f(x) = f(y)$.  If we let $X = [0,1]$ the quotient map, and $p: [0,1] \rightarrow X/ \sim$, then there is a unique continuous map $\bar{f}: X \rightarrow [0,1] \times [0,1]$ for which $\bar{f} \circ p = f$.

Since $\bar{f}$ is a continuous bijection, it's automatically a homeomorphism ($X$ is compact and $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ is Hausdorff).